# Xcode TableView Cell dynamic heights with UITableViewAutoDimension

Tags: ios, xcode, dynamic, uitableview

So, I have an issue that seems to have cropped up after having updated the Xcode program on my Mac. I have a tableView that houses an image and subsequent comments underneath, which are initially offscreen until you scroll down and then they load up. The issue I seem to be having is that the cells wont adjust their heights respectively unless I first scroll down to get them loaded, scroll up and then down again. Only then will the UITableViewAutoDimension seem to take effect.

Any suggestions? My auto-laying is exactly how it should be to accommodate dynamic heights of UILabels.

Let me know if more information is needed.

Cheers in advance.

Comment: Are you running on iOS 7 or 8? TBH Autolayout is a massive headache with tableview cells. Try experimenting with calling -setNeedsLayout and -layoutIfNeeded after you set the content of the cell (ie the text). Try this guide as well, although I still had to tweak to get it working: http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout My advice if you're supporting 7 and 8, is to switch off autolayout and calculate and return the correct height from -heightForCellAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

So after about 10 hours of pulling my hair out and literally debugging to sh*t, I found that I had 'use size classes' selected along with 'use auto constraints' which was completely destroying any chance of the table cells from resizing first time. I switched 'use size classes' off in the interface builder document and it seems to have resolved the issue. All I can say is thank f**k! 👍